# File paths in Ubuntu (python coding)

Tags: python, files

I have a python code  written and working in Windows.
I'm looking to host this application on an Ubuntu server, however I'm not familiar with file path syntax.

In windows it's written as: source='C:/Code/sample.mp3'
I have a folder on my Ubuntu Desktop, so would it be: source='/root/Desktop/Code/sample.mp3' ?

I've tried using this pathing and it the code doesn't appear to work. Have I got it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Windows, Ubuntu (and Linux generally) has a separate folder for every user. These folders are located in /home.

If the "Code/sample.mp3" is located on your users Desktop, the path would be "/home/your_user_name/Desktop/Code/sample.mp3"